# how to make tensorflow ops non trainable

Tags: tensorflow

I'm building a stacked convolutional autoencoder with Tensorflow Core(no API pure Tensorflow). I want to add non trainable layers between encoder and decoder. Does anybody know how to add non trainable layers in tensorflow graph. The tensorboard graph picture is attached, the ops which appears in the blue marked box are the ones that I want to make non trainable, or one can say I do not want gradient computation on them.
TF Version: 1.15
I've tried out tf.stop_gradient() method but this method prevents the contribution of all the input before it. [Tensorboard Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2lr8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- When you define the weights variable with [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) or [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable), pass `trainable=False`. This will stop the variable from being added to the trainable variables collection (accessible through `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)`), which is used by default as the list of variables to train by the optimizer.
- When you define the optimization step with [`minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#minimize) or [`compute_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients), pass a `var_list` argument with the list of variables that you want to train. The optimizer will then ignore the trainable variables collection and will only affect the listed variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is that I'm not creating the variables, I'm just performing some operations on the tensor which are the output of last convolutional layer. And the ops that I added in the custom layers are trainable, as you can see from the [Tensorboard graph](https://i.imgur.com/epxOo2I.png). I want to make these ops non-trainable which are marked with red and are connected with adam optimizer, I want them to disconnect from adam. Here is the code for that layer! [Layer which is shown in the Tensornoard](https://i.imgur.com/85OVBso.png). Thanks for the help again!